# How can I set Html object height same as window height?

Tags: javascript, flash, object

I have flash object embedded to my page and it should act as background animation. I have trouble setting height of object element, because firefox doesn't understand height="100%" value.

```
<object classid="my_class_id" width="100%" height="100%" id="my_id">

<blaa blaa />

</object>
```

Comment: Take a look at this blogpost http://blog.deconcept.com/2005/01/02/100-height-and-100-width-xhtml-flash-embed/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the markup source of the example.

[Fullscreen Flash as BG Example](http://blog.deconcept.com/swfobject/fullpage.html)

Comment: This is same thing nikc  posted and it works. Thanx for help for all people helping me...

Comment: Note that any other divs wrapping around the element will also need to have height set to 100%

Answer (score 0):

You need to set height of `body` and `html` to 100%. Otherwise your object has no parent with a height and it cant use a prozentual value to set the height.

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```